# Unable to build in Appcelerator Studio

Tags: java, titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator

I have a problem with Appcelerator Studio. The build process stucks for a little to:

```
[INFO] :   Running dexer: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin\java.exe "-Xmx512M" "-XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit" "-Djava.ext.dirs=C:\android-sdk-win\platform-tools" "-jar" "C:\android-sdk-win\build-tools\23.0.1\lib\dx.jar" "--dex" "--output=C:\Users\vasilis\Documents\Titanium Projects\pop\build\android\bin\classes.dex" "C:\Users\vasilis\Documents\Titanium Projects\pop\build\android\bin\classes" "C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\android\lib\titanium-verify.jar" "C:\ProgramData\Application Data\Titanium\modules\android\ti.map\2.2.3\map.jar" "C:\ProgramData\Application Data\Titanium\modules\android\ti.map\2.2.3\lib\google-play-services.jar" "C:\ProgramData\Application Data\Titanium\modules\android\ti.cloudpush\3.4.0\cloudpush.jar" "C:\ProgramData\Application Data\Titanium\modules\android\ti.cloudpush\3.4.0\lib\aps-cloudpush-1.1.4.jar" "C:\ProgramData\Application Data\Titanium\modules\android\ti.cloudpush\3.4.0\lib\google-play-services-base.jar" "C:\ProgramData\Application Data\Titanium\modules\android\ti.cloudpush\3.4.0\lib\google-play-services-gcm.jar" "C:\Users\vasilis\Documents\Titanium Projects\pop\modules\android\ti.sq\0.2\tisq.jar" "C:\Users\vasilis\Documents\Titanium Projects\pop\modules\android\com.gbaldera.titouchgallery\1.1\titouchgallery.jar" "C:\Users\vasilis\Documents\Titanium Projects\pop\modules\android\com.rkam.swiperefreshlayout\0.5\swiperefreshlayout.jar" "C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\android\kroll-v8.jar" "C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\android\modules\titanium-analytics.jar" "C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\android\aps-analytics.jar" "C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\android\modules\titanium-android.jar" "C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\android\jaxen-1.1.1.jar" "C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\android\ti-commons-codec-1.3.jar" "C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\android\kroll-common.jar" "C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\android\titanium.jar" "C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\android\modules\titanium-app.jar" "C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\android\modules\titanium-ui.jar" "C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\android\nineoldandroids-appc-2.4.0.jar" "C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\android\modules\titanium-filesystem.jar" "C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\android\modules\titanium-media.jar" "C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\android\modules\titanium-appcompat.jar" "C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\android\android-support-v4.jar" "C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\android\android-support-v7-appcompat.jar" "C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\android\modules\titanium-locale.jar" "C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\android\modules\titanium-network.jar" "C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\android\thirdparty.jar" "C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\android\modules\titanium-xml.jar" "C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\android\modules\titanium-utils.jar" "C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\android\modules\titanium-geolocation.jar" "C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\android\modules\titanium-accelerometer.jar" "C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\android\modules\titanium-contacts.jar" "C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\android\modules\titanium-map.jar" "C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\android\modules\titanium-calendar.jar" "C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\android\modules\titanium-gesture.jar" "C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\android\modules\titanium-platform.jar" "C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\android\modules\titanium-database.jar"
```

and then reuturns me an error

> "Failed to run dexer"

I've tried to uninstall everything, including the Android SDK and install again but with no success

My system has Windows 8.1 OS 64-bit, an i run both 32bit and 64bit versions of Java because I'm learning this period Android Studio.

Comment: maybe [this](https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/164557/failed-to-run-dexer) will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you are using 3.5.1? 4.1.0 already there, update TiSDK, then, run this command and select last version.

```
appc ti sdk select
```

Also make sure you have android-sdk 23, and platform-tool 21, check "[Installing the Android SDK](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Installing_the_Android_SDK)" from Appcelerator Documentation

Also uninstall jdk 1.8 then install 1.7, it has to be 32bit.

Make sure you have enough disk space, 2 GB in same partition of Android SDK installed

Finally to check every think installed correctly run this command

```
appc ti setup check
```